# Build angular and refresh browser on saving files in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I am building an asp.net core 2.2 web app with Angular SPA template. Until a few days ago I could see the browser refresh and reflect changes made on html and typescript files in Visual Studio 2017. Since then, there was an update to both Visual Studio and node modules.

Now the browser doesn't reflect the changes made automatically. I am forced to run an **ng build** command using cmd for the angular app to get the changes on the browser. Is there a setting or configuration that needs to be changed.

I have already enabled **Enable Browser Link** option in the Visual Studio. This is not working.

Visual Studio version is 2017, 15.9.9

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490085/asp-net-core-with-angular-not-updating-changes/53559834#53559834> Same Question asked here