# SQL changes are not displayed in Angular with .NET Core

Tags: sql, angular, iis, .net-core

I have a project that is written in .NET Core 3.1 and Angular 7. I was hosting this project on a server until yesterday. I had to migrate this project to another server. After the migration, I started to have some issues. Whenever I change any SQL data, the Angular component is not refreshed and not displayed the current changes. However, testing it locally, it was fine and works as expected. But when I deployed to the new server, this problem happens.

Specifically, I have a form that I update the users. The update process is working as expected. Not receiving an error. But When I try to edit it again for test purposes, I see unedited data even though SQL database has the edited data.

I did research and found that this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490085/asp-net-core-with-angular-not-updating-changes) already. I followed all of the answers. The issue was not fixed. After that, I thought this could be an SSL issue because .NET Core 3.1 uses SSL for retrieving data. So I even downgraded to 2.1 but I still have the same issue.

The project is working fine with the old server and locally. But I have this issue with the new server after the deployment. I am not sure what to do after this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you get data in Angular? Are you using static page or ajax?  you can try to refresh your page with ctrl +f5 to see if angular component has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research, a lot of debugging and modifications, I found out that (in my case) the issue is not related to .NET core nor Angular. The server has set up that is doing some caching for all sites that go through the proxies for increased performance. This certainly did cause the issue I have. Caching has been removed and everything started to work as expected.